# How to modify the "systemless hosts” file under the newer Magisk?

Tags: magisk, hosts

It seems to be under `/system_root/etc` but the `hosts` file really is just a symbolic link to `/system/etc/hosts`.

How to modify the "systemless hosts” file under the newer Magisk?

Comment: It might look like that, but doesn't Magisk use an overlay file system here?

Comment: What does that mean and what can I do?

Comment: If you doubt Magisk is handling systemless root (and systemless hosts), either don't use it if you want to avoid it – or ask at the [Magisk issue tracker](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/issues) to make sure.

Comment: @Izzy no no, I mean how can I manually modify systemless hosts with adb shell?

Comment: Ah. Well, as you would modify it else: `vi /system/etc/hosts`. The overlay is at file system level, so it should work via ADB as well.

Comment: @Izzy so I would just edit system files as if they were system files but Magisk takes care of the overlay for me?

Comment: That's how I understand it. After all, Magisk claims you can use e.g. AdAway this way – and there's no setting in AdAway for "systemless hosts" (at least there wasn't when I last looked). What's more: What do you guess where the Android system would look for the file? In the "original place" of course. So what sense would it make if that wouldn't resolve to the "systemless hosts" you edited?

Answer (score 3):

In recent versions of Magisk and "Systemless Hosts" module you can no longer directly edit the file `/system/etc/hosts`.

Instead you have to modify the hosts file in the Magisk modules directory of the `hosts` module (the internal name of the "Systemless Hosts" module).

1. Open Magisk -> Settings -> touch `Systemless hosts` (this will create the necessary directory structure and the `hosts` file.
2. Use an editor of your choice and edit the file

```
/data/adb/modules/hosts/system/etc/hosts
```

Any change to that file will directly be visible in `/system/etc/hosts` respectively `/etc/hosts`.

The Magisk modules directory and it's file-system structure is explained here:
https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/guides.html#magisk-modules